# How do I extract the uploaded filename in a POST?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

My form is this:

```
<form name="mail-me" action="/mail-me.py" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id='file' type='file' name='file' />
```

I am doing this within python (I'm using the native google python dev_appserver webapp2.RequestHandler bindings):

```
fileH = self.request.POST["file"]
print(fileH.name)
print(fileH.type)
```

and i get:

```
file
application/octet-stream
```

The file I'm uploading is: `wodim.conf` so I should get wodim.conf instead of `file`. What am I doing wrong - how do i fix this, because I get:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Comment: What does the Server Error have to do with getting the filename?  Seems unrelated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, did a: print(dir(fileH)) - that gave me a list of supported attributes and `filename` is what I should be using, not 'file'. So, `print(fileH.filename)` works. I'm getting the server error because google-app-server only allows a fixed list of extensions (no .exe is allowed for uploading). If you do: `fname = fileH.file` 'file' is returned and this will cause problems since it has no extension (hence the error message).

Answer (score 0):

`request.FILES['filename'].name`
From the [request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) documentation.

You can iterate over the files:

```
for filename, file in request.FILES.iteritems():
    name = request.FILES[filename].name
```

Comment: umm.. that's a link to Django framework docs. I'm not using that. I'm using the native google python cloud bindings `webapp2.RequestHandler`